# condition for joining tables without duplicate in R

Tags: r

I would like to join tables that contain: Radical , notation, date and year. sometimes the radical and year in table1 are the same than the table2. 
so my join should respect this three conditions:

1) If radical of tab1= radical of tab2 and years are different join both

2) If radical of tab1 = radical of tab2 and year of tab1=year of tab2  and note of tab1 = note of tab2, keep one copy without duplicate.

3) If radical of tab1 = radical of tab2 and year of tab1=year of tab2  and note of tab1  different from note of tab2  copy the one where date is more recent for example keep 01/12/2015 instead of 01/10/2015

here is an example of the data:

first table

```
5466    A   2014  01/10/2014

5309    B   2014  01/10/2014

1245    A   2015  01/10/2015

9084    D   2013  01/10/2013

5849    E   2012  01/10/2012

2344    C   2016  01/10/2016

5466    D   2016  01/10/2016
```

second table

```
5466    A   2014   01/10/2014

5309    C   2015   01/10/2015

1245    D   2015   01/12/2015

9084    D   2013  01/10/2013

5849    E   2015  01/10/2015

2344    C   2016  01/10/2016

5849    E   2015  01/10/2015
```

this is an example for two tables, but i might have around 8tables to join with the same condition .

I'm new in R,  any help would be much appreciated

```
**head(dput(table1)**
structure(list(Radical = c(5230097L, 1995719L, 1995001L, 5920591L, 
1236621L, 7641166L), date = structure(c(617L, 617L, 1282L, 1332L, 
1815L, 21L), .Label = c("01/02/2008", "01/02/2010", "01/02/2011", 
"01/02/2012", "01/02/2013", "01/03/2010", "01/03/2011", "01/03/2012", 
"01/03/2013", "01/04/2008", "01/04/2009", "01/04/2010", "01/04/2011", 
"01/04/2013", "01/04/2014", "01/04/2015", "01/06/2009", "01/06/2010", 
"01/06/2011", "01/06/2012", "01/06/2015", "01/07/2008", "01/07/2009", 
"01/07/2010", "01/07/2011", "01/07/2013", "01/07/2014", "01/07/2015", 
"01/08/2008", "01/08/2011", "01/08/2012", "01/08/2013", "01/08/2014", 
"02/07/2009", "02/07/2010", "02/07/2012", "02/07/2013", "02/07/2014", 
"02/07/2015", "02/08/2010", "02/08/2012", "02/08/2013", "02/09/2010", 
"02/09/2011", "02/09/2013", "02/09/2014", "02/09/2015", "02/10/2012", 
"02/10/2013", "02/10/2014", "02/10/2015", "02/11/2009", "02/11/2010", 
"02/11/2011", "02/11/2012", "02/12/2008", "02/12/2009", "02/12/2010", 
"12/05/2010", "12/05/2011", "12/05/2014", "12/05/2015", "12/06/2008", 
"12/06/2009", "12/06/2012", "12/06/2013", "12/06/2014", "12/06/2015", 
"12/07/2010", "12/07/2011", "12/07/2012", "12/07/2013", "12/08/2008", 
"12/08/2009", "12/08/2010", "12/08/2011", "12/08/2013", "12/08/2014", 
"12/08/2015", "12/09/2011", "12/09/2012", "12/09/2013", "12/09/2014", 
"12/10/2009", "12/10/2010", "12/10/2011", "12/11/2008", "12/11/2009", 
"12/11/2010", "12/11/2012", "12/11/2013", "12/11/2014", "12/12/2008", 
"12/12/2011", "12/12/2012", "12/12/2013", "12/12/2014", "13/01/2009", 
"13/01/2010", "13/01/2011", "13/01/2012", "13/01/2014", "13/01/2015", 
"13/02/2008", "13/02/2009", "13/02/2012", "13/02/2013", "13/02/2014", 
"13/02/2015", "13/03/2009", "13/03/2012", "13/03/2013", "13/03/2014", 
"13/03/2015", "13/04/2009", "13/04/2010", "13/04/2011", "13/04/2012", 
"13/04/2013", "13/04/2015", "13/05/2008", "13/05/2009", "13/05/2010", 
"13/05/2011", "13/05/2013", "13/05/2014", "13/05/2015", "13/06/2008", 
"13/06/2009", "13/06/2011", "13/06/2012", "13/06/2013", "13/06/2014", 
"13/07/2009", "13/07/2010", "13/07/2011", "13/07/2012", "13/07/2015", 
"13/08/2008", "13/08/2009", "13/08/2012", "13/08/2013", "13/08/2014", 
"13/08/2015", "13/09/2010", "13/09/2011", "13/09/2012", "13/09/2013", 
"13/10/2008", "13/10/2009", "13/10/2010", "13/10/2011", "13/10/2014", 
"13/11/2008", "13/11/2009", "13/11/2012", "13/11/2013", "13/11/2014", 
"13/12/2010", "13/12/2011", "13/12/2012", "13/12/2013", "14/01/2008", 
"14/01/2009", "14/01/2010", "14/01/2011", "14/01/2013", "14/01/2015", 
"14/02/2011", "14/02/2012", "14/02/2013", "14/02/2014", "14/03/2008", 
"14/03/2011", "14/03/2012", "14/03/2013", "14/03/2014", "14/04/2008", 
"14/04/2009", "14/04/2010", "14/04/2011", "14/04/2014", "14/04/2015", 
"14/05/2008", "14/05/2009", "14/05/2010", "14/05/2012", "14/05/2013", 
"14/05/2014", "14/05/2015", "14/06/2010", "14/06/2011", "14/06/2012", 
"14/06/2013", "14/07/2008", "14/07/2009", "14/07/2010", "14/07/2011", 
"14/07/2014", "14/07/2015", "14/08/2012", "14/08/2014", "14/08/2015", 
"14/09/2009", "14/09/2010", "14/09/2011", "14/09/2012", "14/09/2015", 
"14/10/2008", "14/10/2009", "14/10/2010", "14/10/2011", "14/10/2013", 
"14/10/2014", "14/11/2008", "14/11/2011", "14/11/2012", "14/11/2013", 
"14/11/2014", "14/12/2009", "14/12/2010", "14/12/2011", "14/12/2012", 
"15/01/2009", "15/01/2010", "15/01/2013", "15/01/2015", "15/02/2008", 
"15/02/2010", "15/02/2011", "15/02/2012", "15/02/2013", "15/03/2010", 
"15/03/2011", "15/03/2012", "15/03/2013", "15/04/2008", "15/04/2009", 
"15/04/2010", "15/04/2013", "15/04/2014", "15/04/2015", "15/05/2009", 
"15/05/2012", "15/05/2013", "15/05/2014", "15/05/2015", "15/06/2009", 
"15/06/2010", "15/06/2011", "15/06/2012", "15/06/2015", "15/07/2008", 
"15/07/2009", "15/07/2010", "15/07/2011", "15/07/2013", "15/07/2014", 
"15/07/2015", "15/08/2008", "15/08/2011", "15/08/2013", "15/08/2014", 
"15/09/2008", "15/09/2009", "15/09/2011", "15/09/2014", "15/09/2015", 
"15/10/2008", "15/10/2009", "15/10/2010", "15/10/2012", "15/10/2013", 
"15/10/2014", "15/11/2010", "15/11/2011", "15/11/2012", "15/11/2013", 
"15/12/2008", "15/12/2009", "15/12/2010", "15/12/2011", "15/12/2014", 
"16/01/2009", "16/01/2012", "16/01/2013", "16/01/2014", "16/01/2015", 
"16/02/2009", "16/02/2010", "16/02/2012", "16/02/2015", "16/03/2009", 
"16/03/2010", "16/03/2011", "16/03/2012", "16/03/2015", "16/04/2008", 
"16/04/2009", "16/04/2010", "16/04/2012", "16/04/2013", "16/04/2014", 
"16/04/2015", "16/05/2008", "16/05/2011", "16/05/2012", "16/05/2013", 
"16/05/2014", "16/06/2008", "16/06/2009", "16/06/2010", "16/06/2011", 
"16/06/2014", "16/06/2015", "16/07/2008", "16/07/2009", "16/07/2010", 
"16/07/2012", "16/07/2013", "16/07/2014", "16/07/2015", "16/08/2010", 
"16/08/2011", "16/08/2012", "16/08/2013", "16/09/2008", "16/09/2009", 
"16/09/2010", "16/09/2011", "16/09/2013", "16/09/2014", "16/09/2015", 
"16/10/2008", "16/10/2012", "16/10/2014", "16/11/2009", "16/11/2010", 
"16/11/2011", "16/12/2008", "16/12/2009", "16/12/2010", "16/12/2011", 
"16/12/2013", "16/12/2014", "17/01/2011", "17/01/2012", "17/01/2013", 
"17/01/2014", "17/01/2015", "17/02/2010", "17/02/2012", "17/02/2014", 
"17/02/2015", "17/03/2009", "17/03/2010", "17/03/2011", "17/03/2014", 
"17/03/2015", "17/04/2009", "17/04/2012", "17/04/2013", "17/04/2014", 
"17/04/2015", "17/05/2010", "17/05/2011", "17/05/2012", "17/05/2013", 
"17/05/2014", "17/06/2008", "17/06/2009", "17/06/2010", "17/06/2011", 
"17/06/2013", "17/06/2014", "17/06/2015", "17/07/2008", "17/07/2009", 
"17/07/2012", "17/07/2013", "17/07/2014", "17/08/2009", "17/08/2010", 
"17/08/2011", "17/08/2015", "17/09/2008", "17/09/2009", "17/09/2010", 
"17/09/2012", "17/09/2013", "17/09/2014", "17/09/2015", "17/10/2008", 
"17/10/2011", "17/10/2012", "17/10/2014", "17/11/2008", "17/11/2009", 
"17/11/2014", "17/12/2008", "17/12/2009", "17/12/2010", "17/12/2012", 
"17/12/2013", "17/12/2014", "18/01/2010", "18/01/2011", "18/01/2012", 
"18/01/2013", "18/02/2009", "18/02/2010", "18/02/2011", "18/02/2013", 
"18/02/2014", "18/02/2015", "18/03/2009", "18/03/2011", "18/03/2013", 
"18/03/2014", "18/03/2015", "18/04/2008", "18/04/2012", "18/04/2013", 
"18/04/2014", "18/05/2009", "18/05/2010", "18/05/2011", "18/05/2012", 
"18/05/2015", "18/06/2009", "18/06/2010", "18/06/2012", "18/06/2013", 
"18/06/2014", "18/06/2015", "18/07/2008", "18/07/2011", "18/07/2012", 
"18/07/2013", "18/07/2014", "18/08/2008", "18/08/2009", "18/08/2010", 
"18/08/2011", "18/08/2012", "18/08/2014", "18/08/2015", "18/09/2008", 
"18/09/2009", "18/09/2012", "18/09/2013", "18/09/2014", "18/09/2015", 
"18/10/2010", "18/10/2011", "18/10/2012", "18/10/2013", "18/12/2008", 
"18/12/2012", "18/12/2013", "18/12/2014", "19/01/2009", "19/01/2010", 
"19/01/2011", "19/01/2012", "19/01/2015", "19/02/2009", "19/02/2010", 
"19/02/2013", "19/02/2014", "19/02/2015", "19/03/2009", "19/03/2010", 
"19/03/2012", "19/03/2013", "19/03/2014", "19/03/2015", "19/04/2010", 
"19/04/2012", "19/04/2013", "19/05/2008", "19/05/2009", "19/05/2010", 
"19/05/2011", "19/05/2014", "19/05/2015", "19/06/2008", "19/06/2009", 
"19/06/2012", "19/06/2013", "19/06/2014", "19/06/2015", "19/07/2010", 
"19/07/2011", "19/07/2012", "19/07/2013", "19/08/2010", "19/08/2011", 
"19/08/2013", "19/08/2014", "19/08/2015", "19/09/2008", "19/09/2011", 
"19/09/2012", "19/09/2013", "19/09/2014", "19/10/2009", "19/10/2010", 
"19/10/2011", "19/10/2012", "19/11/2008", "19/11/2009", "19/11/2010", 
"19/11/2012", "19/11/2013", "19/11/2014", "19/12/2008", "19/12/2011", 
"19/12/2012", "19/12/2013", "19/12/2014", "20/01/2009", "20/01/2010", 
"20/01/2012", "20/01/2014", "20/01/2015", "20/02/2008", "20/02/2009", 
"20/02/2012", "20/02/2013", "20/02/2014", "20/02/2015", "20/03/2009", 
"20/03/2012", "20/03/2014", "20/03/2015", "20/04/2009", "20/04/2010", 
"20/04/2012", "20/04/2015", "20/05/2008", "20/05/2009", "20/05/2011", 
"20/05/2013", "20/05/2014", "20/05/2015", "20/06/2008", "20/06/2011", 
"20/06/2012", "20/06/2013", "20/06/2014", "20/06/2015", "20/07/2009", 
"20/07/2010", "20/07/2011", "20/07/2012", "20/07/2013", "20/07/2014", 
"20/07/2015", "20/09/2010", "20/09/2011", "20/09/2012", "20/09/2013", 
"20/10/2008", "20/10/2009", "20/10/2010", "20/10/2011", "20/10/2014", 
"20/11/2008", "20/11/2009", "20/11/2012", "20/11/2013", "20/11/2014", 
"20/12/2010", "20/12/2011", "20/12/2012", "20/12/2013", "21/01/2008", 
"21/01/2009", "21/01/2010", "21/01/2011", "21/01/2013", "21/01/2014", 
"21/01/2015", "21/02/2008", "21/02/2011", "21/02/2012", "21/02/2013", 
"21/02/2014", "21/02/2015", "21/03/2011", "21/03/2012", "21/03/2013", 
"21/03/2014", "21/04/2009", "21/04/2010", "21/04/2011", "21/04/2014", 
"21/04/2015", "21/05/2009", "21/05/2010", "21/05/2012", "21/05/2013", 
"21/05/2014", "21/05/2015", "21/06/2010", "21/06/2011", "21/06/2012", 
"21/06/2013", "21/07/2008", "21/07/2009", "21/07/2010", "21/07/2011", 
"21/07/2014", "21/07/2015", "21/08/2015", "21/09/2010", "21/09/2011", 
"21/09/2012", "21/09/2014", "21/09/2015", "21/10/2008", "21/10/2009", 
"21/10/2010", "21/10/2011", "21/10/2013", "21/10/2014", "21/11/2008", 
"26/05/2015", "26/06/2009", "26/06/2012", "26/06/2013", "26/06/2014", 
"26/06/2015", "26/07/2010", "26/07/2011", "26/07/2012", "26/07/2013", 
"26/07/2014", "26/08/2008", "26/08/2009", "26/08/2010", "26/08/2011", 
"26/08/2013", "26/08/2014", "26/08/2015", "26/09/2008", "26/09/2011", 
"26/09/2012", "26/09/2013", "26/09/2014", "26/10/2009", "26/10/2010", 
"26/10/2011", "26/11/2008", "26/11/2009", "26/11/2010", "26/11/2012", 
"26/11/2013", "26/11/2014", "26/12/2008", "26/12/2011", "26/12/2012", 
"26/12/2013", "26/12/2014", "27/01/2009", "27/01/2010", "27/01/2011", 
"27/01/2014", "27/01/2015", "27/02/2009", "27/02/2012", "27/02/2013", 
"27/02/2014", "27/02/2015", "27/03/2008", "27/03/2009", "27/03/2012", 
"27/03/2013", "27/03/2014", "27/03/2015", "27/04/2009", "27/04/2010", 
"27/04/2011", "27/04/2012", "27/04/2015", "27/05/2008", "27/05/2009", 
"27/05/2010", "27/05/2011", "27/05/2013", "27/05/2014", "27/05/2015", 
"27/06/2008", "27/06/2011", "27/06/2012", "27/06/2013", "27/06/2014", 
"27/07/2009", "27/07/2010", "27/07/2011", "27/07/2012", "27/07/2015", 
"27/08/2008", "27/08/2009", "27/08/2010", "27/08/2012", "27/08/2014", 
"27/08/2015", "27/09/2010", "27/09/2011", "27/09/2012", "27/09/2013", 
"27/10/2008", "27/10/2009", "27/10/2010", "27/10/2014", "27/11/2008", 
"27/11/2009", "27/11/2012", "27/11/2013", "27/11/2014", "27/12/2010", 
"27/12/2011", "27/12/2012", "27/12/2013", "28/01/2009", "28/01/2010", 
"28/01/2011", "28/01/2013", "28/01/2014", "28/01/2015", "28/02/2011", 
"28/02/2012", "28/02/2013", "28/02/2014", "28/03/2011", "28/03/2012", 
"28/03/2013", "28/03/2014", "28/04/2009", "28/04/2010", "28/04/2011", 
"28/04/2014", "28/04/2015", "28/05/2008", "28/05/2009", "28/05/2010", 
"28/05/2012", "28/05/2013", "28/05/2014", "28/05/2015", "28/06/2010", 
"28/06/2011", "28/06/2012", "28/06/2013", "28/07/2008", "28/07/2009", 
"28/07/2010", "28/07/2011", "28/07/2014", "28/07/2015", "28/08/2008", 
"28/08/2009", "28/08/2012", "28/08/2013", "28/08/2014", "28/08/2015", 
"28/09/2009", "28/09/2010", "28/09/2012", "28/09/2015", "28/10/2008", 
"28/10/2009", "28/10/2010", "28/10/2013", "28/10/2014", "28/11/2008", 
"28/11/2011", "28/11/2012", "28/11/2013", "28/11/2014", "28/12/2009", 
"28/12/2010", "28/12/2011", "28/12/2012", "28/12/2013", "29/01/2009", 
"29/01/2010", "29/01/2013", "29/01/2014", "29/01/2015", "29/02/2008", 
"29/02/2012", "29/03/2010", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2012", "29/03/2013", 
"29/04/2008", "29/04/2009", "29/04/2010", "29/04/2011", "29/04/2013", 
"29/04/2014", "29/04/2015", "29/05/2008", "29/05/2012", "29/05/2013", 
"29/05/2014", "29/05/2015", "29/06/2009", "29/06/2010", "29/06/2011", 
"29/06/2012", "29/06/2015", "29/07/2008", "29/07/2009", "29/07/2010", 
"29/07/2011", "29/07/2013", "29/07/2015", "29/08/2011", "29/08/2012", 
"29/08/2013", "29/08/2014", "29/08/2015", "29/09/2008", "29/09/2009", 
"29/09/2010", "29/09/2011", "29/09/2014", "29/09/2015", "29/10/2008", 
"29/10/2009", "29/10/2010", "29/10/2012", "29/10/2013", "29/10/2014", 
"29/11/2010", "29/11/2011", "29/11/2012", "29/11/2013", "29/12/2009", 
"29/12/2010", "29/12/2011", "29/12/2014", "30/01/2009", "30/01/2012", 
"30/01/2013", "30/01/2014", "30/01/2015", "30/03/2010", "30/03/2011", 
"30/03/2012", "30/03/2015", "30/04/2008", "30/04/2009", "30/04/2010", 
"30/04/2012", "30/04/2013", "30/04/2014", "30/04/2015", "30/05/2008", 
"30/05/2011", "30/05/2012", "30/05/2013", "30/05/2014", "30/06/2008", 
"30/06/2009", "30/06/2010", "30/06/2011", "30/06/2014", "30/06/2015", 
"30/07/2013", "30/07/2015", "30/08/2010", "30/08/2012", "30/08/2013", 
"30/09/2008", "30/09/2009", "30/09/2010", "30/09/2011", "30/09/2013", 
"30/09/2014", "30/09/2015", "30/10/2008", "30/10/2009", "30/10/2012", 
"30/10/2013", "30/10/2014", "30/11/2009", "30/11/2010", "30/11/2011", 
"30/11/2012", "30/12/2008", "30/12/2009", "30/12/2010", "30/12/2011", 
"30/12/2013", "30/12/2014", "31/01/2011", "31/01/2012", "31/01/2013", 
"31/01/2014", "31/01/2015", "31/03/2009", "31/03/2010", "31/03/2011", 
"31/03/2014", "31/03/2015", "31/05/2010", "31/05/2011", "31/05/2012", 
"31/05/2013", "31/07/2008", "31/07/2009", "31/07/2012", "31/07/2013", 
"31/07/2014", "31/07/2015", "31/08/2009", "31/08/2010", "31/08/2012", 
"31/08/2015", "31/10/2008", "31/10/2011", "31/10/2012", "31/10/2013", 
"31/10/2014", "31/12/2007", "31/12/2008", "31/12/2009", "31/12/2010", 
"31/12/2012", "31/12/2013", "31/12/2014"), class = "factor"), 
    note = c("B", "A", "A", "B", "E", "B"), year = c(2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L)), .Names = c("Radical", "date", 
"note", "year"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

**Head(put(table2))**

structure(list(Radical = c(5230097L, 5920591L, 1995719L, 1687496L, 
1236621L, 7641166L), date = structure(c(739L, 1437L, 937L, 1315L, 
1957L, 24L), .Label = c("", "01/02/2010", "01/02/2011", "01/02/2012", 
"01/02/2013", "01/02/2016", "01/03/2010", "01/03/2011", "01/03/2012", 
"01/03/2013", "01/03/2016", "01/04/2008", "01/04/2009", "01/04/2010", 
"01/04/2011", "01/04/2013", "01/04/2014", "01/04/2015", "01/04/2016", 
"01/06/2009", "01/06/2010", "01/06/2011", "01/06/2012", "01/06/2015", 
"01/06/2016", "01/07/2008", "01/07/2009", "01/07/2010", "01/07/2011", 
"01/07/2013", "01/07/2014", "01/07/2015", "01/08/2008", "01/08/2011", 
"01/08/2012", "01/08/2013", "01/08/2014", "01/09/2009", "01/09/2010", 
"01/09/2014", "01/09/2015", "01/10/2009", "01/10/2010", "01/10/2012", 
"01/10/2013", "01/10/2014", "01/10/2015", "01/11/2010", "01/11/2011", 
"01/11/2012", "01/11/2013", "01/12/2008", "01/12/2009", "01/12/2010", 
"01/12/2011", "01/12/2013", "01/12/2014", "01/12/2015", "02/01/2008", 
"02/01/2009", "02/01/2012", "02/01/2014", "02/01/2015", "02/02/2009", 
"02/02/2010", "02/02/2011", "02/02/2012", "02/02/2015", "02/02/2016", 
"02/03/2009", "02/03/2010", "02/03/2011", "02/03/2012", "02/03/2015", 
"02/03/2016", "02/04/2009", "02/04/2010", "02/04/2012", "02/04/2013", 
"02/04/2014", "02/04/2015", "02/05/2011", "02/05/2012", "02/05/2013", 
"02/05/2014", "02/05/2016", "02/06/2009", "02/06/2010", "02/06/2011", 
"02/06/2014", "02/06/2015", "02/06/2016", "02/07/2009", "02/07/2010", 
"02/07/2013", "02/07/2014", "02/07/2015", "02/08/2010", "02/08/2012", 
"02/08/2013", "02/09/2009", "02/09/2010", "02/09/2011", "02/09/2013", 
"02/09/2014", "02/09/2015", "02/10/2012", "02/10/2013", "02/10/2014", 
"02/10/2015", "02/11/2009", "02/11/2010", "02/11/2011", "02/11/2012", 
"02/11/2015", "02/12/2008", "02/12/2009", "02/12/2010", "02/12/2011", 
"02/12/2013", "02/12/2014", "02/12/2015", "03/01/2011", "03/01/2012", 
"03/01/2013", "03/01/2014", "03/02/2009", "03/02/2010", "03/02/2011", 
"03/02/2014", "03/02/2015", "03/02/2016", "03/03/2008", "03/03/2009", 
"03/03/2010", "03/03/2011", "03/03/2014", "03/03/2015", "03/03/2016", 
"03/04/2009", "03/04/2012", "03/04/2013", "03/04/2014", "03/04/2015", 
"03/05/2010", "03/05/2011", "03/05/2012", "03/05/2013", "03/05/2016", 
"03/06/2008", "03/06/2009", "03/06/2010", "03/06/2011", "03/06/2013", 
"03/06/2014", "03/06/2015", "03/06/2016", "03/07/2008", "03/07/2012", 
"03/07/2013", "03/07/2014", "03/07/2015", "03/08/2009", "03/08/2010", 
"03/08/2011", "03/08/2012", "03/08/2015", "03/09/2008", "03/09/2009", 
"03/09/2010", "03/09/2013", "03/09/2014", "03/09/2015", "03/10/2008", 
"03/10/2011", "03/10/2012", "03/10/2013", "03/10/2014", "03/10/2015", 
"03/11/2008", "03/11/2009", "03/11/2010", "03/11/2011", "03/11/2014", 
"03/11/2015", "03/12/2008", "03/12/2009", "03/12/2012", "03/12/2013", 
"03/12/2014", "03/12/2015", "04/01/2008", "04/01/2011", "04/01/2012", 
"04/01/2013", "04/01/2014", "04/01/2016", "04/02/2008", "04/02/2009", 
"04/02/2010", "04/02/2011", "04/02/2013", "04/02/2014", "04/02/2015", 
"04/02/2016", "04/03/2008", "04/03/2009", "04/03/2010", "04/03/2011", 
"04/03/2013", "04/03/2015", "04/03/2016", "04/04/2011", "04/04/2012", 
"04/04/2013", "04/04/2014", "04/04/2016", "04/05/2009", "04/05/2010", 
"04/05/2011", "04/05/2012", "04/05/2015", "04/05/2016", "04/06/2009", 
"04/06/2010", "04/06/2012", "04/06/2013", "04/06/2014", "04/06/2015", 
"04/07/2008", "04/07/2012", "04/07/2013", "04/07/2014", "04/07/2015", 
"04/08/2008", "04/08/2009", "04/08/2010", "04/08/2014", "04/08/2015", 
"04/09/2008", "04/09/2009", "04/09/2012", "04/09/2013", "04/09/2014", 
"04/09/2015", "04/10/2010", "04/10/2011", "04/10/2012", "04/10/2013", 
"04/11/2008", "04/11/2009", "04/11/2010", "04/11/2011", "04/11/2013", 
"04/11/2014", "04/11/2015", "04/12/2008", "04/12/2009", "04/12/2012", 
"04/12/2013", "04/12/2014", "04/12/2015", "05/01/2009", "05/01/2011", 
"05/01/2012", "05/01/2016", "05/02/2009", "05/02/2010", "05/02/2013", 
"05/02/2014", "05/02/2015", "05/02/2016", "05/03/2009", "05/03/2010", 
"05/03/2012", "05/03/2013", "05/03/2014", "05/03/2015", "05/04/2010", 
"05/04/2011", "05/04/2012", "05/04/2013", "05/04/2016", "05/05/2008", 
"05/05/2009", "05/05/2010", "05/05/2011", "05/05/2014", "05/05/2015", 
"05/05/2016", "05/06/2008", "05/06/2009", "05/06/2012", "05/06/2013", 
"05/06/2014", "05/06/2015", "05/07/2010", "05/07/2011", "05/07/2012", 
"05/07/2013", "05/08/2008", "05/08/2009", "05/08/2010", "05/08/2011", 
"05/08/2013", "05/08/2014", "05/08/2015", "05/09/2011", "05/09/2012", 
"05/09/2013", "05/09/2014", "05/10/2009", "05/10/2010", "05/10/2011", 
"05/10/2012", "05/10/2015", "05/11/2008", "05/11/2009", "05/11/2010", 
"05/11/2012", "05/11/2014", "05/11/2015", "05/12/2008", "05/12/2011", 
"05/12/2012", "05/12/2013", "05/12/2014", "06/01/2009", "06/01/2010", 
"06/01/2011", "06/01/2014", "06/01/2015", "06/01/2016", "06/02/2009", 
"06/02/2013", "06/02/2014", "06/02/2015", "06/03/2008", "06/03/2012", 
"06/03/2013", "06/03/2015", "06/04/2009", "06/04/2010", "06/04/2011", 
"06/04/2012", "06/04/2015", "06/04/2016", "06/05/2008", "06/05/2009", 
"06/05/2010", "06/05/2011", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2014", "06/05/2015", 
"06/05/2016", "06/06/2008", "06/06/2011", "06/06/2012", "06/06/2013", 
"06/06/2014", "06/06/2016", "06/07/2009", "06/07/2010", "06/07/2011", 
"06/07/2012", "06/07/2015", "06/08/2008", "06/08/2010", "06/08/2012", 
"06/08/2013", "06/08/2014", "06/08/2015", "06/09/2010", "06/09/2011", 
"06/09/2012", "06/09/2013", "06/10/2008", "06/10/2009", "06/10/2010", 
"06/10/2011", "06/10/2015", "06/11/2008", "06/12/2010", "06/12/2012", 
"06/12/2013", "07/01/2009", "07/01/2010", "07/01/2011", "07/01/2013", 
"07/01/2014", "07/01/2015", "07/01/2016", "07/02/2011", "07/02/2013", 
"07/02/2014", "07/03/2008", "07/03/2011", "07/03/2012", "07/03/2013", 
"07/03/2014", "07/03/2016", "07/04/2009", "07/04/2010", "07/04/2011", 
"07/04/2014", "07/04/2015", "07/04/2016", "07/05/2008", "07/05/2009", 
"07/05/2010", "07/05/2012", "07/05/2013", "07/05/2014", "07/05/2015", 
"07/06/2010", "07/06/2011", "07/06/2012", "07/06/2013", "07/06/2016", 
"07/07/2008", "07/07/2009", "07/07/2010", "07/07/2011", "07/07/2014", 
"07/07/2015", "07/08/2008", "07/08/2009", "07/08/2012", "07/08/2013", 
"07/08/2014", "07/08/2015", "07/09/2009", "07/09/2010", "07/09/2011", 
"07/09/2012", "07/09/2013", "07/09/2015", "07/10/2008", "07/10/2009", 
"07/10/2010", "07/10/2011", "07/10/2013", "07/10/2014", "07/10/2015", 
"07/11/2008", "07/11/2012", "07/11/2013", "07/11/2014", "07/11/2015", 
"07/12/2009", "07/12/2011", "07/12/2012", "07/12/2015", "08/01/2009", 
"08/01/2013", "08/01/2014", "08/01/2015", "08/01/2016", "08/02/2008", 
"08/02/2010", "08/02/2011", "08/02/2012", "08/02/2013", "08/02/2016", 
"08/03/2010", "08/03/2011", "08/03/2012", "08/03/2013", "08/03/2016", 
"08/04/2008", "08/04/2009", "08/04/2010", "08/04/2011", "08/04/2013", 
"08/04/2014", "08/04/2015", "08/04/2016", "08/05/2008", "08/05/2009", 
"08/05/2012", "08/05/2013", "08/05/2014", "08/05/2015", "08/06/2009", 
"08/06/2010", "08/06/2011", "08/06/2012", "08/06/2015", "08/06/2016", 
"08/07/2009", "08/07/2010", "08/07/2011", "08/07/2013", "08/07/2014", 
"08/07/2015", "08/08/2009", "08/08/2011", "08/08/2012", "08/08/2013", 
"08/08/2014", "08/08/2015", "08/09/2008", "08/09/2009", "08/09/2010", 
"17/06/2010", "17/06/2011", "17/06/2013", "17/06/2014", "17/06/2015", 
"17/06/2016", "17/07/2008", "17/07/2009", "17/07/2012", "17/07/2013", 
"17/07/2014", "17/08/2009", "17/08/2010", "17/08/2011", "17/08/2015", 
"17/09/2008", "17/09/2009", "17/09/2010", "17/09/2012", "17/09/2013", 
"17/09/2014", "17/09/2015", "17/10/2008", "17/10/2011", "17/10/2012", 
"17/10/2014", "17/11/2008", "17/11/2009", "17/11/2014", "17/11/2015", 
"17/12/2008", "17/12/2009", "17/12/2010", "17/12/2012", "17/12/2013", 
"17/12/2014", "17/12/2015", "18/01/2011", "18/01/2012", "18/01/2013", 
"18/01/2016", "18/02/2009", "18/02/2010", "18/02/2011", "18/02/2013", 
"18/02/2014", "18/02/2015", "18/02/2016", "18/03/2009", "18/03/2011", 
"18/03/2013", "18/03/2014", "18/03/2015", "18/03/2016", "18/04/2012", 
"18/04/2013", "18/04/2014", "18/04/2016", "18/05/2009", "18/05/2010", 
"18/05/2011", "18/05/2012", "18/05/2015", "18/05/2016", "18/06/2009", 
"18/06/2010", "18/06/2012", "18/06/2013", "18/06/2014", "18/06/2015", 
"18/07/2008", "18/07/2011", "18/07/2012", "18/07/2013", "18/07/2014", 
"18/08/2008", "18/08/2009", "18/08/2010", "18/08/2011", "18/08/2014", 
"18/08/2015", "18/09/2008", "18/09/2009", "18/09/2012", "18/09/2013", 
"18/09/2014", "18/09/2015", "18/10/2010", "18/10/2011", "18/10/2012", 
"18/10/2013", "18/12/2008", "18/12/2012", "18/12/2013", "18/12/2014", 
"18/12/2015", "19/01/2009", "19/01/2010", "19/01/2011", "19/01/2012", 
"19/01/2015", "19/01/2016", "19/02/2009", "19/02/2010", "19/02/2013", 
"19/02/2014", "19/02/2015", "19/02/2016", "19/03/2009", "19/03/2010", 
"19/03/2012", "19/03/2013", "19/03/2014", "19/03/2015", "19/04/2010", 
"19/04/2012", "19/04/2013", "19/04/2016", "19/05/2008", "19/05/2009", 
"19/05/2010", "19/05/2011", "19/05/2014", "19/05/2015", "19/05/2016", 
"19/06/2008", "19/06/2009", "19/06/2012", "19/06/2013", "19/06/2014", 
"19/06/2015", "19/07/2010", "19/07/2011", "19/07/2012", "19/07/2013", 
"19/08/2009", "19/08/2010", "19/08/2011", "19/08/2013", "19/08/2014", 
"19/08/2015", "19/09/2011", "19/09/2012", "19/09/2013", "19/09/2014", 
"19/10/2009", "19/10/2010", "19/10/2011", "19/10/2012", "19/10/2015", 
"19/11/2008", "19/11/2009", "19/11/2012", "19/11/2013", "19/11/2014", 
"19/11/2015", "19/12/2008", "19/12/2011", "19/12/2012", "19/12/2013", 
"19/12/2014", "20/01/2009", "20/01/2010", "20/01/2012", "20/01/2014", 
"20/01/2015", "20/01/2016", "20/02/2008", "20/02/2009", "20/02/2012", 
"20/02/2013", "20/02/2014", "20/02/2015", "20/03/2009", "20/03/2012", 
"20/03/2014", "20/03/2015", "20/04/2009", "20/04/2010", "20/04/2012", 
"20/04/2015", "20/04/2016", "20/05/2009", "20/05/2011", "20/05/2013", 
"20/05/2014", "20/05/2015", "20/05/2016", "20/06/2008", "20/06/2011", 
"20/06/2012", "20/06/2013", "20/06/2014", "20/06/2015", "20/06/2016", 
"20/07/2009", "20/07/2010", "20/07/2011", "20/07/2012", "20/07/2014", 
"20/07/2015", "20/09/2010", "20/09/2011", "20/09/2012", "20/09/2013", 
"25/02/2013", "25/02/2014", "25/02/2015", "25/02/2016", "25/03/2009", 
"25/03/2010", "25/03/2011", "25/03/2013", "25/03/2015", "25/03/2016", 
"25/04/2011", "25/04/2012", "25/04/2013", "25/04/2014", "25/04/2016", 
"25/05/2009", "25/05/2010", "25/05/2011", "25/05/2012", "25/05/2015", 
"25/05/2016", "25/06/2008", "25/06/2009", "25/06/2010", "25/06/2012", 
"25/06/2013", "25/06/2014", "25/06/2015", "25/06/2016", "25/07/2008", 
"25/07/2011", "25/07/2012", "25/07/2013", "25/07/2014", "25/08/2008", 
"25/08/2009", "25/08/2010", "25/08/2011", "25/08/2014", "25/08/2015", 
"25/09/2008", "25/09/2009", "25/09/2012", "25/09/2013", "25/09/2014", 
"25/10/2010", "25/10/2011", "25/10/2012", "25/10/2013", "25/11/2008", 
"25/11/2009", "25/11/2010", "25/11/2011", "25/11/2013", "25/11/2014", 
"25/11/2015", "25/12/2008", "25/12/2009", "25/12/2012", "25/12/2013", 
"25/12/2014", "26/01/2009", "26/01/2010", "26/01/2011", "26/01/2012", 
"26/01/2015", "26/01/2016", "26/02/2008", "26/02/2009", "26/02/2010", 
"26/02/2012", "26/02/2013", "26/02/2014", "26/02/2015", "26/02/2016", 
"26/03/2009", "26/03/2010", "26/03/2012", "26/03/2013", "26/03/2014", 
"26/03/2015", "26/04/2010", "26/04/2011", "26/04/2012", "26/04/2013", 
"30/10/2008", "30/10/2009", "30/10/2012", "30/10/2013", "30/10/2014", 
"30/10/2015", "30/11/2009", "30/11/2010", "30/11/2011", "30/11/2012", 
"30/11/2015", "30/12/2008", "30/12/2009", "30/12/2010", "30/12/2011", 
"30/12/2013", "30/12/2014", "30/12/2015", "31/01/2011", "31/01/2012", 
"31/01/2013", "31/01/2014", "31/01/2016", "31/03/2009", "31/03/2010", 
"31/03/2011", "31/03/2014", "31/03/2015", "31/03/2016", "31/05/2010", 
"31/05/2011", "31/05/2012", "31/05/2013", "31/05/2016", "31/07/2008", 
"31/07/2009", "31/07/2012", "31/07/2013", "31/07/2014", "31/07/2015", 
"31/08/2009", "31/08/2010", "31/08/2012", "31/08/2015", "31/10/2008", 
"31/10/2011", "31/10/2012", "31/10/2013", "31/10/2014", "31/12/2007", 
"31/12/2008", "31/12/2009", "31/12/2010", "31/12/2013", "31/12/2014", 
"31/12/2015", "94 467 322 287"), class = "factor"), note = c("B", 
"B", "A", "D", "DEF", "B"), year = c(2016L, 2015L, 2016L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L)), .Names = c("Radical", "date", "note", "year"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` to generate code for your example data.

Comment: How can I use dput()?

Comment: just type `dput(mytable1)` to generate code that will enable us to get the exact object you have in your `R` environment (substitute `mytable1` with the names of your table objects).

Comment: for Radical 1245 we have 2 different notes with same date, so we can't take the most recent

Comment: @LAP here is what i've got from dput(table1) Names = c("Radical", 
"date", "note", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15688L))

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yes sorry i've forgot to include different date  in the example, i've edited it now

Comment: @Maha, this is only part of your output. It usually begins with `structure(list(...` and ends with the line you posted.

Comment: @LAP yes indeed, it's so long here is a part of it  
2014L, 2012L, 2010L, 2012L, 2012L, 2010L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2008L, 2012L, 2010L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2010L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2012L, 2010L, 2012L, 2010L, 2011L, 2009L, 2008L, 2011L, 
2010L, 2008L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2010L, 2010L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2008L, 2012L, 2011L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2009L, 2009L, 2008L, 2010L, 2015L, 2014L)), .Names = c("Radical", 
"date", "note", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15688L))

Comment: Please just edit it all into your question instead of putting it in a comment. If it is too long, try `dput(head(table1))`. Also do the same for `table2`.

Comment: @LAP i've edited it into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work, but we really need input data to do better :

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1,df2) %>%
  distinct %>%
  group_by(Radical,year) %>%
  top_n(1,date) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: the output                                             
   Radical date    note   year
     <int> <chr>      <chr> <int>
 1 5230097 11/05/2015 B      2015
 2 1995719 11/05/2015 A      2015
 3 1995001 22/05/2015 A      2015
 4 5920591 23/03/2015 B      2015
# ... with 23,633 more rows
Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector